# Compile a Java project with Java6

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6

for reasons of deployment and "versions" of tomcat, I need to use Java 6.

So I downloaded the JDK 6 : 1.6.0_45 and I updated my environment variables :

> JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
>
> JRE_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre

I'm working with NetBeans and I configured some things. In the properties of my server (JBoss), I changed the Java Platform to JDK 1.6. After that I updated the properties of my project (`Right click on my project>Properties>Compile > Java Platform = JDK 1.6` )

When I check the version of Java which compiled my project, I can see Java 7.

---> In command prompt : `javap -verbose MyClass`
But it says `major version = 51` which means Java 7.

Did I forgot to change something in NetBeans to compile with Java 6 ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Note that a Java 7 compiler still can produce Java 6 compatible code (which probably is happening in your case). Check the resulting class files.

Comment: @Thomas So why I can't deploy my project on a virtual machine which work with Java 6 ?

Comment: Does the VM tell you there's a class with an unsupported version? If so you really have some Java 7 classes on your classpath. Check whether they all are recompiled and if yes and they still have class version 51 then check the compiler logs (don't know where they are in Netbeans).

Comment: Its rather clear that Netbeans is still using a Java 7 JDK to compile stuff and the project is setup to produce Java 7 compatible classes. There is no need to ask that, you're already proving it.